# How to debug a kubernetes pod whose status is error

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, containers

I am building my *docker* image and then deploy using *kubernetes*.

When I execute the command:

```
kubectl get pods 

NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
lmhfhfhf-def-abc            0/1     Error   0          2m
```

I am almost sure that, it's because of my code changes.  How do I debug this pod to find out the logical error in my code.

Please Help.

Comment: Easiest way is by checking the logs of your Pod and a describe. Can you post the result of kubectl logs pod-name, kubectl logs pod-name --previous and kubectl describe pod pod-name ?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community @witti_minds

@user2830517 and @andD have generally answered it, however I'd like to add a bit more details and sources.

Your pod is crashed, however since it was scheduled, options used for running pods will work ([k8s debug unhealthy pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#my-pod-is-crashing-or-otherwise-unhealthy))

First you should get all information about your pod by running a following command, this will give you all information about your pod ([k8s pod inspection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/)):

```
kubectl describe pod %pod_name%
```

Then you should do is to examine POD's logs using following command:

```
kubectl logs lmhfhfhf-def-abc %container_name%
```

Container name is optional here, if your pod has more than 1 container, you have to use it.
Also you can check logs from previous state of the pod:

```
kubectl logs --previous %pod_name% %container_name%
```

Once you have your container up and running, you can continue troubleshooting your application by running command directly in pod using `exec` command:

```
kubectl exec -it %pod_name% -- sh
```

There are different types of possible troubleshooting methods, they are all described here [k8s debugging a running pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following things

1. Check Pod events using **"kubectl describe"**

> *kubectl describe pod pod-name*

2. Check pod related logs using

> *kubectl logs pod-name*

3. Check all events of your Kubernetes Cluster

> *kubectl get events*

Comment: @st.huber tbf I think the onus is on the poster here.  This user's answer is a sufficient start to start to look for issues given the level of details in the question.